# Checking through intent if user has certain messaging app installed android

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-number

I am working with this code which Ragu Swaminathan helped me with on my original post found at: [How to show both texting and dialer apps with a single Intent on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990682/how-to-show-both-texting-and-dialer-apps-with-a-single-intent-on-android/34995375?noredirect=1#comment57725010_34995375).

```
final List<Intent> finalIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
final Intent textIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
textIntent.setType("text/plain");
textIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
final PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(textIntent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
  final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
  final Intent intent = new Intent(textIntent);
  intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
  intent.setPackage(packageName);
  finalIntents.add(intent);
}

Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:121"));
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(
        callIntent, "Select app to share");

chooserIntent.putExtra(
        Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, finalIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

I have this code that brings up snackup separating sms and dialer apps installed on users phone and allows them to pick one to either send a message / call a person.

What I want to know is, is it possbile to add another section on this snackbar that checks if the user has whatsapp installed or another specfic app installed.

Also, being new to android, I have tried playing around with the code but ended up messing it up. another thing that I would like to do is create sections like theses;

Sms apps:

.....

.....

.....

Dialer apps:

.....

.....

.....

Whatsapp:

.....

Any help is welcomed, please let me know if my question is not clear.

Edited;

[image]

Comment: you are asking about the grouping of apps by messaging / call in the native intent ?

Comment: It is possible to check that particular app installed or not

Comment: Please can you show me an example @RaguSwaminathan

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getPackageInfo` method

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(certainAppPackageName, 0);

if (pi != null) {
    //app is installed, do smth
}
```

Google play links exist package names.
For example:

```
 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.messenger
```

where `org.telegram.messenger` is a package name

Comment: how can I get the package name or is this the name of the app?

Comment: Google play links exist package names: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.messenger`

Comment: For example, I want to check if the user has whatsapp, if so, I want to allow them to send a message through whatsapp. Do I can I achieve this?

Comment: As in their google play link: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp`. Use `"com.whatsapp"` as a package name,

Comment: Its not working, it gives me an error on getPackageManager(), it says cannot resolve method getPackageManager() and also it does not recognise the packageName.

Comment: `getPackageManager()` is a `Context` method, you need a context object to use it.

Comment: Please could you give me an example, I have never came across context before

Comment: pass an `Activity` object to your function (as it inherits `Context`) or use [a static way to get 'Context'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android)

Comment: I have done this;     PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", 0);

        if (pi != null) {
            //do smth
        }
but it still doesn't understand the package name

Comment: do you want to show only selected apps in the dialog. ?

Comment: Yes, so I want to get three sections in the dialog, one that says sms apps containing list of texting apps, another section called dialer apps, containing dialer apps and finally another section whatsapp, and if whatapp is found I want to show whats app inside it.

Comment: then you can go with custom view. You cannot do sectioning in the native intent.

Comment: oh ok, when I write the package name, it does not recognise it.

Comment: @henry, nothing happens in `if`-section?

Comment: You need to handle this exception with `try-catch`. It is thrown when a given package cannot be found.

Comment: Thanks, putting try-catch removed the error but when I run the app, whatsapp doesn't show up.

Comment: yep, I tried running the code in if-section it still doesn't show whatsapp

Comment: put there `Log.d("Tag","Whatsapp is installed");` and check your log records

Comment: Whats app is installed because I am testing it on my device which has whatsapp

Comment: it says: 01-25 20:05:54.629 21982-21982/com.contact.others D/Tag: Whatsapp is installed